# C#: Scope-specific variable binding

Tags: c#, binding, variables, scope

In some languages, there are things like these:

Lisp:

```
(let ((x 3))
  (do-something-with x))
```

JavaScript:

```
let (x = 3) {
  doSomethingWith(x);
}
```

Is there anything like this in C#?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can limit the scope of a value type variable with curly brackets.

```
{
    var x = 3;
    doSomethingWith(x);
}
generateCompilerError(x);
```

The last line will generate a compiler error as `x` is no longer defined.

This will work for object types as well, but doesn't guarantee when the object will be disposed after it falls out of scope. To ensure that object types **which implement IDisposable** are disposed in a timely manner use `using`:

```
using (var x = new YourObject())
{
    doSomethingWith(x);
}
generateCompilerError(x);
```

Comment: Additionally, this is what people are talking about when they say "block level scoping"

Answer (score 1):

You can use block to scope names. From C# Specification:

> 8.2 Blocks
>
> A block permits multiple statements to be written in contexts where a single statement is allowed.
>
> block:  {   statement-listopt   }
>
> A block consists of an optional
>   statement-list (§8.2.1), enclosed in
>   braces. If the statement list is
>   omitted, the  block is said to be
>   empty.
>
> A block may contain declaration
>   statements (§8.5). The scope of a
>   local variable or constant declared in
>   a block is the block.
>
> Within a block, the meaning of a name
>   used in an expression context must
>   always be the same (§7.5.2.1).